# TooManyRequestsException: Rate exceeded. while deleting many cognito users at a time

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am using **AWS sdk** in my NodeJS Application to Delete the Cognito Users.

When i am trying to delete multiple users (Ex. 25-30 users) using the [AdminDeleteAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDeleteUser.html), I am getting **TooManyRequestsException** error.

Which is obvious as per the [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDeleteUser.html).

What is the best way to handle this?

Right now i am planning to wait for 1-2 seconds then again start deleting from the same user for which i got exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cognito has a soft limit of 10 AdminRemoveUserFromGroup request per second ([1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html)).

You could open a support case to increase the limit : [AWS Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html).